# Laravel acessors, relations and eager loading

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have a Laravel app with a few forms and CRUD operations. On the app I have a relation like this:

Brand column (on Guns table) references ID on Brands table.

Gun model:

```
public function brand()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('Brand', 'brand', 'id');
}
```

Brand Model:

```
public function gun()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Gun', 'id', 'brand');
}
```

That is working if I try to load guns data from the controller, using with, like that:

$results = Gun::with('brand')->findOrFail($id);

However, everytime I want to use a Form model to display gun data, the brand shows as an ID, not the brand name.

I tried setting an Accessor for that, like this (Gun model):

```
public function getBrandAttribute ($id)
{
    $attribute = Brand::find($id);

    return ($attribute ? $attribute->value : $id);  
}
```

It works, but when I return a list with all the guns on the database, it takes a lot of time.

How can I set an accessor from the model that will return the brand name without having to do a query everytime?

I var_dump $this on the accessor and I see the gun data, but I can't see the data from the brand table.

Answer (score 0):

When you are eager loading, you don't want to call `$gun->brand` to get the name of the brand.  That's already been setup to return the `Brand` model.  In order to get the name of a brand of gun, you would do something like this:

```
$gun->brand->name;
```

This is assuming you have a `name` column in your `brands` table.

You could also set it in the accessor by reaching into the relation which has already been setup.

```
public function getBrandAttribute()
{
    return $this->brand->name;
}
```

Beware though that Laravel already setup this accessor and with this method, you'd be overwriting that.  I'd suggest using a different attribute if you can, ex... getBrandNameAttribute()

Comment: That doesn't work inside the model when setting the accessor getBrandAttribute.

Comment: You don't need the accessor `getBrandAttribute`, you use `$gun->brand->name;` to get the brand name of a gun.  No changes to models necessary.

Comment: Yes but I need to use accessors for other purpose. I need to automatically show the brand name, not the ID.

Comment: Usually the answer to that is to create a dropdown for that field with all the brands and the values of the options would be the id.  This way when you use `Form::model()`, it sets the correct value using ID but still shows the name.

Comment: I've updated the answer, it should give you what you want without having to requery the database as long as you've already eager loaded that relation.

Comment: Thanks user3158900, but I'm generating docx files from laravel. I need the data to go to the file with the value from brands table, not the id. I'm using a library and I can't send data like this: $gun->brand->name. I need to send as it is, from the database. That's why the accessor is the only option now.

Comment: Even the accessor I just added to my answer will not work?

Comment: I tried your solution, however, I get the following error: Undefined property: Gun::$brand

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get accessors directly with eager loading.  You have to append the object when you are using it.

```
$guns = Gun::with('brand')->findOrFail($id);

foreach($guns as $gun){
   $gun->brand->setAppends(['brand']);

   //logic
   $brand = $gun->brand->brand;
}
```